# Showing Projected field does not exist in schema: line:bytearray

Tags: python, hadoop

1)I have loaded a folder in Apache.Pig without defining delimiter given as LINE. 
2)I have used PYTHON  udf's to filter the given string.But I m getting the above error.

```
REGISTER '/home/hadoop/alanGates/filter.py' using jython as filterfunction;
d = load '/home/hadoop/Desktop/' using PigStorage as line;
M = foreach d generate filterfunction.tuple_contains(line,Mariko);
```

Anyone could sought out this error and give me solution.

Comment: `describe` or `explain` your relation `d` and you'll be able to debug it better.